# 10.11 unexpected behavior

Tags: macos, mouse

I have something they weird with a few app (e.g mail, message...)

E.g in Message, when I have my cursor on the top of a conversation and I scroll to the left to delete the conversation, the UI stop responding (but the process is still working fine)

I removed com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist but didn't help

Screenrecording https://app.box.com/s/xeo38qxk3i0evw6vl0817tgtl3rhaus5

[Screenrecording](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=e6olds&s=9) [TinyPic](http://tinypic.com)

Comment: can you post the recording to somewhere everyone can view it?

Comment: What kind of mouse do you have?  I had a brand new Logitech BT mouse and it suffered lag just like that.

Comment: I will try to upload somewhere else / I have a Magic Mouse

Answer (score 1):

You are not first how met this problem.

- [Mail Won't Respond To Mouse Clicks](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7372477?searchText=mail%20mouse)
- [Magic Mouse doesn't select in Mail after El Capitan](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7389472?searchText=mail%20mouse)

From above support request no one doesn't know any workaround for resolving this rude bug. Hope it will be fixed at the nearest updates.

Answer (score 0):

I take it back in my case removing this plist solved the issue

> ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist